# On skew monoid rings and skew ordered series rings

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids

To my knowledge (see, e.g., H.H. Brungs and G. Törner's *Skew Power Series Rings and Derivations* [J. Algebra 87 (1984), 368-379]), skew polynomial rings were first introduced by Ø. Ore in 1933: Given an (associative, unital) ring $R$, a ring endomorphism $\sigma$ of $R$, and a [$\sigma$-derivation](https://planetmath.org/sigmaderivation) $\delta$, we can *uniquely*${}^{(1)}$ define a (binary) operation $\cdot$ on the set $\mathfrak F_{00}(\mathbb N, R)$ of all finitely supported functions $\mathbb N \to R$ such that

- the triple $(\mathfrak F_{00}(\mathbb N, R), +, \cdot\,)$ is a ring, where $+$ is the operation of pointwise addition on $\mathfrak F_{00}(\mathbb N, R)$, and
- $(\chi_1 + a\chi_0) \cdot b\chi_0 = \sigma(b) \chi_1 + (ab + \delta(b))\chi_0$ for all $a, b \in R$, where $\chi_i$ is, for each $i \in \mathbb N$, the indicator function of $\{i\}$ as a subset of $\mathbb N$ and we are viewing the group $(\mathfrak F_{00}(\mathbb N, R), +)$ as a left $R$-module in the obvious way${}^{(2)}$.

Now, in the same way as polynomial rings (in arbitrarily many variables) are generalized by monoid rings (so recovering, among many others, Laurent polynomial rings and free algebras in one go), it seems natural to me to extend Ore's definition to *skew monoid rings* (however defined) and then to *skew ordered series rings* (which, however defined, should in turn provide a natural generalization of ordered series rings in the sense of P.M. Cohn's 2006 book on FIRs and localization${}^{(3)}$). So the question is:

> **Q.** Where can I read about skew monoid rings [*edit:* answered by Benjamin Steinberg [in a comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430307/on-skew-monoid-rings-and-skew-ordered-series-rings)${}^{(4)}$] and skew ordered series rings (giving for granted that they have been considered before in the literature)?

I could only dig up papers dealing with special cases of what I'd consider a satisfactory definition of a skew monoid ring (resp., a skew ordered series ring), and I wonder if there is a good reason for that (beyond the fact that people may have found such a thing not especially interesting after all).

**Notes.**

(1) See, e.g., Sect. 5.2 in [P.M. Cohn, *Introduction to Ring Theory*, Springer, 2004 (3rd ed.)].

(2) You may want to introduce a formal variable $X$ and set $X^i := \chi_i$ (see [Pace Nielsen's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430307/on-skew-monoid-rings-and-skew-ordered-series-rings#comment1107283_430307)).

(3) AFAIK, ordered series rings were first introduced by R.E. Johnson in *Unique factorization monoids and domains* [Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 28 (1971), No. 2, 397-404] (please correct me if I'm wrong on this point). One starts with a linearly ordered monoid $\mathcal H = (H, \preceq)$ and consider the set $\mathcal W(\mathcal H, R)$ of all functions $f \colon H \to R$ whose support $s(f) := H \setminus f^{-1}(0_R)$ is well ordered under $\preceq$ (in the sense that the restriction of $\preceq$ to $s(f)$ results in a well-ordered set). If $f, g \in \mathcal W(\mathcal H, R)$, then
$$
\Gamma(u) := \{(x, y) \in H \times H \colon xy = u \text{ and } f(x) g(y) \ne 0_R\}
$$
is a finite set for every $u \in H$ (see Sect. 2 in Johnson's paper), so one can turn $\mathcal W(\mathcal H, R)$ into a ring $R[\![\mathcal H]\!]$ by taking the sum $f+g$ of $f$ and $g$ to be their pointwise sum and the product $fg$ of $f$ by $g$ to be the function $H \to R \colon u \mapsto \sum_{(x, y) \in \Gamma(u)} f(x) g(y)$. Cohn refers to $R[\![\mathcal H]\!]$ as the ring of ordered series of $\mathcal H$ over $R$.

(4) The reference provided by Benjamin Steinberg is [E.P. Cojuhari, *Monoid algebras over non-commutative rings*, Internat. Electron. J. Algebra 2 (2007) 28-53], where the author seems to expand on an idea of Brungs and Törner's paper (the same cited at the beginning of this post), but only for skew monoid rings (whereas Brungs and Törner deal with rings of skew power series).

Comment: Skew monoid rings and more generally crossed products certainly exist and have been studied. Karpilovsky has some stuff on them

Comment: Does Karpilovsky's definition recover Ore's? Or does it only refer to _twisted_ monoid rings (where the derivation $\delta$ is trivial)?

Comment: I have to check.  I'm having trouble assimilating your definition

Comment: I think crossed products don't have the derivation

Comment: You can maybe start here https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/generalized-higher-derivations/A0081BAAF0351D47EEEA371390664629

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I'll check, thanks. By the way, I maybe see now what you meant by "I'm having trouble assimilating your definition": My post had at least a couple of mistakes.

Comment: Salvo, first off I would recommend simplifying your notation.  Finitely supported functions $\mathbb{N}\to R$ are nothing more than polynomial rings.  So, rather than work with indicator functions, it is much more convenient to use powers of a polynomial variable $x$ (subject to $\sigma$-$\delta$-skewing).  Second, a good place to start studying these skew polynomial rings is the paper "Primeness, semiprimeness and prime radical of Ore extensions" by Lam, Leroy, and Matczuk https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927879708826000

Comment: Pace: Yeah, one could just set $x^i := \mathbf 1_i$ and observe that $\mathbf 1_i \cdot \mathbf 1_i = x^{i+j}$ (I know that!). But for me it's somehow easier to work with indicator functions than with "formal sums" involving one variable for each element of the monoid H, though I admit that, in the classical case of polynomial rings _in finitely many variables_, this may be (unnecessarily) confusing. As for the rest, I've already checked Lam's A first course, but I can only find skew polynomial (resp., skew power series) rings therein. So, I'll try with the paper you're suggesting.

Comment: You might look at http://www.ieja.net/files/papers/volume-2/Volume-1--2007/3-V2-2007.pdf

Comment: I agree with Pace.  It's why I had trouble with your definition

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg As for skew monoid rings, Cojuhari's paper (the one linked in your comment https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430307/#comment1107321_430307) is just perfect (thanks!): The defs there are much more general than what I had in mind. Anything about skew ordered series rings? I can't find them mentioned (possibly under a different name) in any of the papers that have so far been brought into the discussion (including the one by Lam et al. suggested by Pace in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430307/=1#comment1107283_430307)

Comment: Power series only generalize to monoids where each element has finitely many factorizations do I don't know how general people have gone

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Edited the OP to include some details of how ordered series rings are being defined.

Comment: As pointed out by Daniel Smertnig (Univ. of Graz, IMSC) in private communication, Johnson series are a minor generalization of Hanh series (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_series#Formulation). In short, I would put it down like this: Totally ordered groups are to Hanh series as linearly ordered monoids are to Johnson series.